# online compiler

Tags: compiling, deb, open-source

An open-source author didn't provide the binary file, but just the source code, for users to download and compile them self. Downloading and installing compilers is required and needs time to try and disk space to store. Can I use an online compiler to create a .deb or .rpm file from the source code?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSUSE has something which you might be interested in: https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Build_Service